# SWRevealViewController and passing objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to pass an object to my rear `UIViewController` when I reveal it. I set up the `SWRevealViewController` in the interface builder. I tried passing it in `prepareForSegue` for segue id "sw_rear" however I noticed that this isn't even called when the controller is revealed. Could anyone give me a pointer on how to do this please?

Comment: How did you figure it out? And which segue identifier did you use to send the data? I'm running into the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue before.
prepareForSegue is not called from controllerA as it does not own controllerB.
You can access to your rear just writting: self.revealViewController.rearViewController from any instance that inherits from SWRevealViewController.

Comment: Hi, i have the same issue, so which segue identifier did you use? If i use "sw_rear" it doesn't even fire